# EmberCLI runtime configuration

Tags: docker, ember.js, configuration, environment-variables, ember-cli

We're running an EmberCLI application in our infrastructure, and I'm tasked to make it work better with the rest of our services. One thing that's a bit interesting about EmberCLI is that all it's configuration variables are baked into the build by default. (Specifically in the `<meta>` tag).

I had trouble finding a way to supply runtime configuration. We have an "API_URL" environment variable that's supplied to all our services so they can find the API. What is the recommended way to supply this url to EmberCLI at run-time, so I can avoid a rebuild and have fully-built docker containers with our frontend application.

Comment: An interesting question is what you use for your server? Ember, as a client side application, will never be able to access an environment variable! And if you put your app into docker, how do you set this variable inside the docker container? Probably its best to replace the `meta` tag at some point instead of setting the environment variable. Your server could even do this at runtime, but for performance/caching its better to do this only on startup/buildtime.

Comment: @Lux yea I'm actually looking to do this during startup time. I'm curious basically what the ember-cli considers to be a good approach for this. Settings in docker are passed via the `--e` argument, and this is a pretty common way to pass run time settings.

Comment: Worst case scenario is that I make changes to the `<meta>` tag using sed, before startup, but I was hoping to find something that works a bit better within the ember ecosystem.

Comment: And what us your server? Nginx, apache, iis? I think this should be done by your web server!

Comment: From your answer I take it it's a "no" then ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an environment variable for configuration [ember-cli-dotenv](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-cli-dotenv) will help. It allows you to access an environment variable in `config/enviroment.js`:

```
// config/environment.js
module.exports = function(environment){
  return {
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL
  }
};
```

You have to whitelist the environment variables used in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    dotEnv: {
      clientAllowedKeys: ['API_URL']
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

A short side note: Configuration variables are baked into the build by ember-cli cause ember-cli has done it's job after build. Files generated should be served by a normal webserver like nginx. The webserver which could be started with `ember serve` should not be used in production.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. What if I _do_ want to dynamically specify variables after a build. Even if this is not ember-cli's job, I'm curious if there's an accepted best practice within the ember-cli community. I can't be the only one using docker in a sane manner ;)

Comment: If you need to change it after build, I don't see any other possibility than manipulation meta tag.

Comment: Alright, I will take that as a "no" or "I don't know". You're right, there's some hacking I can do to make it work, and I've certainly considered it, but I was hoping to find some kind of accepted best practice.